# Separate template for typdef types

Tags: c++, templates, typedef

I've created a template class that outputs values based on their data types i.e. long gets output as a signed integer (decimal), whereas `RESULT` gets output in hex format. I defined `RESULT` as:

```
typdef long RESULT.
```

This isn't working correctly because `RESULT` is being treated like a `long` and `RESULT`'s output routine never gets called (instead `long`'s routine is called). Is there a workaround for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you want will not work for the reasons given.

How about just adding a Function object that formats the output as you want.

```
class A {
    template< typename T>
    std::string output(long val) {return T(val)}
}

struct decimal {
    std::string operator()(long val) {//return decimal}
}

struct hex {
    std::string operator()(long val) {//return hex}
}
```

A sample use case:

```
A a;
cout << a.output<decimal>(10) << endl;
cout << a.output<hex>(10) << endl;
```

Comment: SO is serious business, typos will not be tolerated.

Answer (score 1):

This is expected.

A typedef doesn't alter how the compiler sees the type -- it creates a new name for the type, in this case RESULT, and as it is the same type, it behaves and uses the same code as the type specified, in this case long.

Comment: I think what you want to say is that it creates a new name for the same type. It specifically does **not** create a new type.

Answer (score 1):

`typedef` declares only `alias` for type. You can use some "`template magic`" for your example.

```
template<typename T, int I>
struct true_typedef
{
    explicit true_typedef(const T& val):value(val) { }
    T value;
};

typedef true_typedef<long, 0> RESULT;
```

example.

http://liveworkspace.org/code/1fc907ae5cddc23bd7d9545cfafa8a05

Comment: that's really neat, but unfortunatley, I'm not allowed to change the definition of RESULT

Comment: @tunafish24: And you don't think that mentioning such constraints in the question would be a good idea?